# Transfer textview data between activities?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm currently making an app that has edittext and 2 buttons, everytime I write something in to edittext and then press button1, a new textview is added. This is the code:

```
public void novVnos (View v){
    EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(eText.getText().toString()));
}

private TextView createNewTextView (String text){
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);

    newTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    newTextView.setText(text);
    return newTextView;
}
```

Basically what I'm doing is adding new "players" and once I've added them all I want to press button2. Button2 opens a new activity and the new activity should read all the textviews that I've added in the previous activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a "Player" `class` and make a `static ArrayList<String> players` inside your `Player.java` class. Every time you call `createNewTextView(textView)` add whatever variable `text` is to the `players` `ArrayList`.

In your next `Activity` you just call `Player.players.get(index)` or whatever `ArrayList` function you need to do whatever work you want with it in the next class. You also could create this `ArrayList` in your current `Activity` and pass it as an extra in the `Intent` but I think creating a separate class for the players would be easiest.

Your `ArrayList` obviously doesn't need to hold `String`s. It could hold whatever you want including a Player object.

[ArrayList Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: I'm new in programming so it'll take some time until I completely understand this and make it happen but I'll do my best and let you know how it went as soon as I'm done. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I hope it works for you. Also, if this seemed pretty unclear then you really will be better off if you get a better understanding of OOP before attempting to build Android programs. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

this is an example :

in the first activity :

```
   Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, result.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            EditText searchtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);

            b.putString("searchtext", searchtext.getText().toString());
                   //Add the set of extended data to the intent and start it
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_ACTIVITY);
        }
    });
```

and in the second activity at onCreat :

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String searchtext = b.getString("searchtext"); //here you get data then use it as you want

  //here I use it to show data in another edittext
     EditText etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtext2);
     etSearch.setText(searchtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a "Player" class will be a way to go. In that regard, you don't have to worry about transferring data between two activities. You can use Singleton method to make sure your class has been defined only once. You need to make sure it gets defined only once because let's say if you user closes application or kills app, then when he opens app again, it would create another class, so all of your data will be lost.